# Where is the print spooler data stored in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, printing, print-spooler

Where are files generated by printer drivers stored in Windows 7? I mean the intermediate file generated by the printer driver when we click "Print".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The spooler and related bits reside in [Drive]:\windows\system32\spool.

I can't think of any other reason you'd ask this question offhand so I'll throw this out there - if you're specifically trying to clear out a print queue manually, empty spool\printers.  **Make sure you stop the spooler service before you do this.**

Answer (score 0):

Well I can find a valid reason and that is if the only local printer has an current unsolvable connection problem and the print status holds a job that cannot be easily retrieved again so want send to a application that can save it as pdf locally

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).